# matplotlib.animate saves only one still frame

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg, scatter-plot

**EDIT**

Changed the presented code so that another person can take it away and reproduce the error. The data for the below code can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ra0xqmn81esiyiz/AAA4rEOk4vjtKrVbufHjCcMua?dl=0), including the code and the animation produced.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Plotting Clevis LVDT Displacements"
    os.chdir(r"F:\BrokenAnimation")
    animation_data = np.loadtxt("animation_data.csv", delimiter=",")
    time = animation_data[:,0] 
    L10 = animation_data[:,1]
    L11 = animation_data[:,2]
    L12 = animation_data[:,3]

    def data_gen():
        t = data_gen.t
        cnt = 0
        L10_iter = data_gen.L10_iter
        L11_iter = data_gen.L11_iter
        L12_iter = data_gen.L12_iter
        while cnt < 35000:
            cnt+=1
            t += 10.0
            yield [-10.25, L10_iter.next()], [10.1875, L11_iter.next()],
                  [L12_iter.next(), -9.0] 
    data_gen.t = 0
    data_gen.L10_iter = iter(np.array(L10))
    data_gen.L11_iter = iter(np.array(L11))
    data_gen.L12_iter = iter(np.array(L12))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    scat = ax.scatter([0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

    ax.set_xlim(-15, 15)
    ax.set_ylim(-10.0, 0.5)
    ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 0.5)
    ax.grid()


    def run(data):
        # update the data
        x, y, z = data
        scat.set_offsets([x, y, z])
        return scat,

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, data_gen,
                                  blit=True, interval=40, # 40msec? implying 25fps?
                                  )

    # This works
    plt.show()

    # Doesn't really save what I see in plt.show()
    ani.save('South_Clevis.mp4') # 435kb file 4 sec long, 25 fps 800x600 887Kbps
```

I'm trying to plot a time history of the displacements of the dots below:

[image: aaa]

The dots at y = 0.0 are the original positions and the animation moves the dots up and down. For context, the dots represent LVDT displacements over a time history of 35,000 sec with a sample rate of 1 per second. So each "second" the plot should be updated.

Bitrate does not appear to be a keyword that actually does anything. I have ffmpeg installed and it is on the Windows path. Using the [basic writer example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example_writer.html) (but without the line `matplotlib.use("Agg")`, because python complained) works fine and produces an animation that can be played back.

Comment: Given that the basic writer example worked, the problem may be with the animation itself. Can you post code for an animation that does not save properly?